# Redshift WHERE to find current month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
TO_CHAR(order_placed_at_ltz,'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(NOW(),'YYYY-MM')
```

it gives me this error:

> ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

I want to get the orders placed for this month according to some queries that I made and I put the `TO_CHAR` function in a WHERE condition  .

Comment: Please, do not spam your question with unrelated tags!

Comment: If you want to find orders in the current month, you can use: `DATE_TRUNC('month', order_placed_at_ltz) = DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

According to Redshift documentation on [date and time functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html), it does not have a `now()` function. Use `getdate()` or `current_date()` function instead.

Comment: Thatnks <3 current_date() did work

Comment: @OmarHitham perhaps you could mark the answer as accepted...